# justify-content: space-around; - как при нечетном количестве блоков выставить последний элемент под левый блок над ним?

Tags: html, css

"Детский вопрос", но не помню ответа.Есть "main" с "flex-flow: wrap;" "justify-content: space-around" с нечетным кол-вом блоков внутри по 2 на строчку. Как можно поставить последний блок под левый блок на строчку выше. ("justify-content: space-around" делает последний нечетный блок посередине строчки). "margin-left: auto;" для последнего элемента будет толкать нечетный к стенке "main", а не под верхний левый блок.
UPD: размеры блоков хаотичны

```
<style>
   main{
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: wrap;
     justify-content: space-around;
     width: 300px;
   }
   div{
     width: 125px;
   }
</style>

<main>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извините, наверное не в тему, так как нужно было на flex решить, но на grid легче)).
Если нужно, что бы блоки зелёные занимали большую площадь, нужно просто вместо 2fr сделать 3fr например.
На flex сделал вариант, но это уже не space-around, а space-evenly получается.

```css
main{
 display: grid;
 gap: 15px;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
}
div{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background: green;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}


section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 15px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
section div {
  width: 30%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 calc((100% - (30% * 2)) / 4);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>

<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо Вам, рабочий вариант, но проблема в том, что все мои стили 'едут' и придется в таком варианте менять все стили как на декстопе так и в адаптиве. Если альтернативы не будет - воспользуюсь вашим вариантом.

Comment: @Burr_DI Посмотрите на flex сделал, но это получилось justify-content: space-evenly, а не space-around. Ну может вам такое пойдёт)).

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас фиксированная ширина родителя и блоков (как в примере), то Вы можете задать конкретный margin с другой стороны от auto:

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: wrap;
     justify-content: space-around;
     width: 300px;
     border: 1px solid red;
}
div {
     width: 125px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     padding: 30px;
}
div:last-child {
     margin: 0 auto 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
</main>
```

Или можете добавить в конец чётный блок и скрыть его с помощью opacity:

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: wrap;
     justify-content: space-around;
     width: 300px;
     border: 1px solid red;
}
div {
     width: 125px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     padding: 30px;
}
div:last-child {
     opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: спасибо, но ширины хаотичны. Добавил после Вашего ответа пометку

Comment: @Burr_DI, тогда вариант со скрытым чётным блоком. Ну или js использовать